# Magento on PHP 7.2 wamp server

Tags: wamp, magento-1.9, mcrypt, php-7.2

i am configuring an existing magento project on local system with WAMP server php version 7.2, while installing magento i get error "PHP extension "mcrypt" must be loaded."
Problem is mycrypt is no longer supported in php 7.2, can anyone suggest how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mcrypt has been moved from php to pecl since 7.2

You still can install it.

Install dependencies

```
gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
```

install the lib itself

```
libmcrypt-dev
```

I assume php7.2 and pecl are installed so you just install mcrypt-1.0.1 (or whatever version is in rep.) with pecl

```
pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
```