# getting Error "undefined function mcrypt_create_iv()" in php 7.2 In Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3, php-7.2

I am getting below error

> ERROR - 2018-10-01 12:05:23 --> Severity: error --> Exception: Call to undefined function mcrypt_create_iv() /var/www/html/application/controllers/api.php 331

deploying app on AWS EC2 ubuntu 16( Php 7.2, Nginx, codeigniter 3.1.9)

Answer (score 8):

mcrypt is removed from php7.2. can not use in PHP 7.2. i have created new function and added in common helper.

```
if (!function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv')) {
    function mcrypt_create_iv($length) {
        return openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length, NULL);
    }
}
```

might be helpful to other users.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52549847/magento-on-php-7-2-wamp-server

Comment: Only variables can be passed by reference , solved here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17279734/7839573

Answer (score 0):

install mcrypt

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mcrypt
sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
```

Answer (score 0):

This polyfill is useful for backwards compatibility w/ mcrypt on PHP 7.3:

https://github.com/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat